# AWS High RDS MYSQL DB Connections goes always high up to 500+ connections and website running with PHP Nginx get crashed everyday

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, rds

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated or if any more information needed to dig out lemme know ill update and share.

Comment: I think it's best to contact the AWS customer support and explain your issue. They have pretty good support.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply but it's really first thing i have tried with AWS support already but nothing relevant they have found on their side. :(

Comment: That's too bad. I don't think we can do anything either without any knowledge about your project setup / code that's responsible for establishing a connection with RDS.

Comment: any thing which i can able to share here if something i can get help !!!!!

Comment: A large number of db connections is going to be a *symptom* of the problem, not the *cause*. The question that only you can answer is "why does my web server sometimes use so many connections?"  The query `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` will tell you what each connection is doing at the moment, and your web server logs should also be useful.  You need an understanding of what is triggering the behavior before you can troubleshoot it. This is almost certainly caused not by RDS, but by your site code and visitor actions, so of course AWS support will correctly say their service is functioning normally.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your reply i will surely collect my required information whenever will get spikes their..